# Javascript array.length returns 0 after .push() in d3.csv() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

```
 const disorders=[];
    const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoirebeaufils/bdc33d6da0fb98eacf4b6c7d630c280b/raw", function(data){
        const disorder = data.disorder;
        disorders.push(data.disorder);

   });

  console.log(disorders)
  console.log(disorders.length)
  console.log(arr)
```

My array shows a length of 5 in the console when I expand the [] tab, but `disorder.length` returns 0 and I can't access any elements.

[image: Array elements and length displayed in the console when expanding the [] tab]

The first array works well and also shows the number of elements as well as the elements in the array without needing to expand the tab. I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it so that the second one works properly.

Comment: `d3.csv()` is an *asynchronous* function. If you log the length inside the callback function, you'll see that it works.

Comment: the data is not ready. When you log disorders the function is still running. Use callback or promises

Answer (score 1):

Since the d3.csv() works async, you need to have a callback function for that:

for eg:

```
const disorders=[];
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function execute(callback) {
   d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoirebeaufils/bdc33d6da0fb98eacf4b6c7d630c280b/raw", function(data){
     const disorder = data.disorder;
     disorders.push(data.disorder);
     callback(disorders);
   });
}

execute(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
   console.log(result.length)
   console.log(arr)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm working with React and I'd like for the disorders array to be passed in the attribute of a component to be used within that component. I was wondering if there was a way to access the array and the array.length in the component just like you did in the callback function. I can't seem to access them and array.length returns 0.